# How to parse/filter data from JSON file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Is there any way to parse/filter the data present in JSON file in a Javascript file.

Basically, I am calling JSON file into my local javascript. I am having trouble in reading specific data and printing.

Can anyone please help.

JSON file contains:

```
{
    "Data": [
    {

    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
    },

    {
    "joined on":"Jan 2015",
    "working on": "Automation",
    }
]
}
```

I am trying to read the above JSON file as:

```
var jfile = require("./Example.json");

var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jfile))

console.log(test)
```

I get the output like this:

```
{ Data:
   [ { name: 'John', age: 30 },
     { 'joined on': 'Jan 2015', 'working on': 'Automation' } ] }
```

From the above, I am interested in accessing/filtering out only one i.e. "name". I would like to print only the value "John" to the console.

I have tried to use the ".filter" method to the JSON.parse method but it throws me an error as:

```
JSON.parse(...).filter is not a function
```

Is there any way to perform this activity?

Comment: `var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jfile))` — Why?!

Comment: @Quentin - I am very new to JSON and still learning, saw at various places to use it this way, Hence I tried to implement the same

Answer (score 2):

You can access it using `.` dot notation

```js
var a = {
  "Data": [{

      "name": "John",
      "age": 30
    },

    {
      "joined on": "Jan 2015",
      "working on": "Automation",
    }
  ]
}
console.log(a.Data[0].name)
```

Comment: I have the values in a separate JSON file and I am trying to access these objects in my javascript file. Does the dot notation still work ?

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is an array method.

`JSON.parse(...)` will not give you an array. It will give you an object with a `Data` property. The value of that property is an array.

`JSON.parse(...).Data.filter`.

You can't just ignore parts of your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **multiple items** in your array of **different shapes**, you can use this

1. Access the `Data` key with `json.Data`
2. `map` your array to transform its items into `names`
3. apply `filter(Boolean)` to take out those who are undefined

In your case you'll end up with an array containing only one name *John*

```js
const getName = json => json.Data.map(x => x.name).filter(Boolean);

const json = {
  "Data": [{

      "name": "John",
      "age": 30
    },

    {
      "joined on": "Jan 2015",
      "working on": "Automation",
    }
  ]
};

console.log(getName(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON's main level is an object (not an array) and only arrays have `.filter` method.
So filter the array under `Data` key:

```
var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jfile)).Data.filter(/*something*/);
```

But better if you aren't re-parse JSON:

```
var test = jfile.Data.filter(/*something*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) mentioned in his comment, What is the use of below statement ?

> var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jfile))

You can directly access the `name` property from the response.

**Try this :**

```js
var obj = {
 "Data": [{

   "name": "John",
   "age": 30
  },

  {
   "joined on": "Jan 2015",
   "working on": "Automation"
  }
 ]
};

// Solution 1
console.log(obj.Data.map(item => item.name).filter(Boolean));

// Solution 2
console.log(obj.Data.filter(item => item.name).map(elem => elem.name));
```

Comment: Why adding json in a variable? what about a local json file with million of lines, how to load it and apply filter on it ?

Comment: In OP, there is a small JSOn that's the only reason i put that in a variable. Its all about the requirement.